# Photo counter reset

Tags: camera, photos

I have Android 4.0.4 on my Sony Xperia Ion (LT28at). It never saves photo counter - everytime I empty DCIM/100ANDRO folder, it begins creating photos from DSC_0001.jpg.

Is there a way to set this counter to specific value, by the way? To change filename mask?

I am not sure if this question is for the Android Enthusiasts, couldn't find any better.

Comment: I don't have that device to hand so I can't check the settings. AFAIK if it isn't in the settings (and I really doubt it is) you cannot change it. You could look for an alternative camera app that might have that functionality.

Comment: What happens if you leave the one file with the highest count in the name and delete the rest?